# Trying to understand output from JavaScript eval which does String parsing

Tags: javascript, eval, string-parsing

Can anyone explain me why the following Java code which executes the JavaScript return "Smith" here?

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    String jsSnippet = "var fullName = 'Joe Smith'; fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1);";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(jsSnippet));
```

Similar JavaScript code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs2501/xaJg4/1/)) which gives the same output as above Java code is

```
var jsSnippet = "var fullName = 'Joe Smith'; fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf(' ') + 1);";
document.write(eval(jsSnippet));
```

PS: I know eval is evil, but this is one of the circumstances I have to use JavaScript eval.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  A return value of `Smith` is what I would expect from the JS you have.

Comment: The question is unclear. You have 2 snippets of identical JS, and you say they both return the same value. What's the problem?

Comment: @broofa & Alex - There is no problem in the JS code, but I have not added any return statement in the eval, then why does the eval return the "Smith". And why it doesn't work if I add return statement in eval? http://jsfiddle.net/hs2501/xaJg4/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eval function evaluates the last expression passed into it, and returns its value. See [the relevant section on eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Return_value) at the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: I have not added any return statement in the eval, then why does the eval return the "Smith". And why it doesn't work if I add return statement in eval? jsfiddle.net/hs2501/xaJg4/2

Comment: Oh, the last expression is implicitly returned. Couldn't work out what you were asking, but there's your answer.

Comment: @Hemant, here's the relevant explanation of eval from the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Return_value